# Clarification on Properties, "Synthesize", and "Dynamic" in Objective-C 2.0

Tags: ios5, dynamic, properties, synthesize

If I define a property in Objective-C 2.0 as follows:

```
@property (readwrite, assign) NSObject *theObject;
```

I have to create getter & setter methods somehow. As far as I can tell, I have three options for this.

- Manually code the implementations of `- (NSObject *)theObject` & `- (void)setTheObject:(NSObject *)object`
- Use `@synthesize` to automatically generate *both* methods, or
- Use `@dynamic` to automatically generate any of the two methods that I don't choose to override.

Am I understanding this correctly? Also, how does the use of different `@property` arguments affect the results of `@synthesize` & `@dynamic`? (For example, `nonatomic` & `weak`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood the difference between `@synthesize` and `@dynamic`.

`@synthesize` will generate the getter and setter methods of the properties if the getter and/or setter has not already been implemented manually.  This is what you currently believe `@dynamic` does.

`@dynamic` is used when you don't want the runtime to automatically generate a getter and setter AND you haven't implemented them manually.  Basically, `@dynamic` is telling the compiler that the getter/setter will be provided dynamically at runtime using some sort of runtime *magic*.

For example, the [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html) says:

```
You can implement the methods `resolveInstanceMethod:` and `resolveClassMethod:` 
to dynamically provide an implementation for a given selector for an instance 
and class method respectively.
```

I suggest you read the [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17) section of [The Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH1-SW2) Language as this explains in much more detail the way `@property`, `@synthesize` and `@dynamic` work along with all the attributes like `nonatomic` and `weak`.

Comment: This is what I originally thought, however, this error message tells a different tale: `Writable atomic property theObject cannot pair a synthesized getter with a user-defined setter`.

Comment: I think this is because, as the error message says, it's an atomic property. Objective-C can't maintain its atomicity guarantees if you define your own setter. Try with non-atomic.

Answer (score 2):

`@dynamic` tells the compiler that the accessor methods are provided at runtime.

With a little bit of investigation I found out that providing accessor methods override the `@dynamic` directive.

`@synthesize` tells the compiler to create those accessors for you (getter and setter)

`@property` tells the compiler that the accessors will be created, and that can be accessed with the dot notation or `[object message]`